# Pierce a hole on the edge of a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to pierce a hole through a cylinder :

[image]

I've tried knife project and boolean/difference with this cylinder and it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I've edited my post as, at first, I didn't understand your question

The easiest way would be this one:

- Create 2 circles
- Merge them
- Delete some vertices
- Fulfill the shape with F
- Extrude with E and press Z to constraint on the Z axis

but it also depends on what you want to do with this shape later on

[image]

Comment: i was just thinking .. one lazy option here, to reduce the distortion of the inner circle as much as possible, would be to create it with way too many vertices, so the Alt-M would move the chosen ones as little as possible, then checker-deselect (invert selection > delete) the excess vertices?

Comment: of course, I was just exposing a simple way to do it, it can be improved a lot, also, I don't know if this shape will have to be changed later on (will it need an extrusion for example?), in that case it could not be the best way to do it

Comment: Both your answers were really useful to me, so I chose this one but this other one is what I should have done from the beginning. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Knife Project works fine.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add -> Mesh -> Circle 32 verts Add another cicle with 16 verts.

Scale down the 16 verts circle.

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the faces in edit mode for both circles.

Adjust the smaller circle at the corner of the big circle.

Now select the smaller circle and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the larger circle and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and type **knife project**

A cut selection is made press <kbd>delete</kbd> select faces

Now delete the smaller circle.

[image]